# is there a way to prevent multiple dots html input tag keypress event using [javascript]

Tags: javascript, html

numberic value worked correctly but i confused to prevent multiple dots input. is there a way to solve this issue?

HTML TAG

```
<input type="text" class="form-control num" />
```

javascript [**work only numeric**]

```
$('input.form-control.num').keypress(function (e) {
        var a = [];
        var k = e.which;
        for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
            a.push(i);
        if (!($.inArray(k, a) >= 0))
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I needed to add a dot and prevent multiple dots for example decimal points **10.9** good.
any way to prevent **10.1.5.1** and prevent start with dot like **.50.9**

after added dot e.charCode

```
$('input.form-control.num').keypress(function (e) {
        var a = [];
        var k = e.which;
        if(e.charCode === 46)
            a.push(e.charCode);
        for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
            a.push(i);
        if (!($.inArray(k, a) >= 0))
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand, do you want the function yo return with an error when it finds a not properly formed number?

Comment: `for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
            a.push(i);
        if (!($.inArray(k, a) >= 0))` is just a very complicated `if( k >= 48 && k < 58 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add checks to your JavaScript like so:

```js
$('input').keypress(function (e) {
        var a = [];
        var k = e.which;
        if(e.charCode === 46) {
            // if dot is the first symbol
            if(e.target.value.length === 0 ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            
            // if there are dots already 
            if( e.target.value.indexOf('.') !== -1 ) {
               e.preventDefault();
               return;
            }   
            
            a.push(e.charCode);
        }
        for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
            a.push(i);
        if (!($.inArray(k, a) >= 0))
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<input type="text">
</form>
```

Alternatively, you could just use `<input type="number">` which [should do the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) for you automatically without any JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses function `setupField` to initialize an input field with an `onkeyup` handler. The current, presumably valid value of the input field is saved. After every change to the input field is made, the new content of the input field is compared with a passed regular expression, `re`, for validation. If the new field value does not pass this validation, the last valid value the filed had is restored. Otherwise, the new current valid field value is saved. So this is a general purpose function that can be used for limiting the input of a text field to whatever you want by varying the regex that you pass. The regex for this particular problem is:

```
/^(?!.*\..*\.)[0-9.]*$/
```

This allows digits and decimal points in the input but uses a *negative lookahead* to ensure that there are not more than two decimal points in the input.

```js
function setupField(field, re)
{
    field.autocomplete = "off";
    field.saveValue = field.value;
    field.onkeyup = function() {
        var v = field.value;
        if (v === '' || re.test(v)) {
            field.saveValue = v;
        }
        else {
            field.value = field.saveValue;
        }
    };
}

let re = /^(?!.*\..*\.)[0-9.]*$/;
setupField(document.f.x, re);
```

```html
<form name="f">
   <input name="x" type="input">
</form>
```

Of course, if you want signed numbers, you can add `+` and `-` to the legal characters allowed.